# Multiple dates in Bootstrap date-picker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to select multiple dates in [Boostrap-Datepicker.](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

I have intialized the datepicker as such, just fine.

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker();
```

Now I want to [select multiple dates](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#setdate) on the calendar:

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', [new Date(2014, 2, 5),new Date(2014, 3, 5)]);
```

It's not working. No errors are logged but the dates are not selected.

---

**EDIT:** the datepicker version I used had some issue with multidates, I used a previous version and it works - probably a version issue

---

*This works just fine though:*

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2014, 2, 5));
```

Comment: Is this a start date/end date situation? If so you could look at using a daterangepicker

Comment: no i just need to illuminate certain dates

Comment: Looks like there's a separate [setDates](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#setdates) method

Comment: yup thats what i use..Am I missing something in the format of my arguments?

Comment: In the code you provided in your question you used `setDate` instead of `setDates`. Note the pluralization

Comment: That's right, thanks but it's still not working.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is necessary to first define your datepicker as a multidate picker through the options.

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
  multidate: true
});
```

Then you can set your dates via the `setDates` method :

```js
$('.date').datepicker({
    multidate: true
});

$('.date').datepicker('setDates', [new Date(2014, 2, 5), new Date(2014, 3, 5)])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control date"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also set limit for number of dates to be select. See below example, you will be able to select only 5 dates maximum.

**Example**

```js
$("#Txt_Date").datepicker({
    format: 'd-M-yyyy',
    inline: false,
    lang: 'en',
    step: 5,
    multidate: 5,
    closeOnDateSelect: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type="text" id="Txt_Date" placeholder="Choose Date" style="cursor: pointer;">
```