# setDates for 3 months for bootstrap multidate picker

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

How can I set **pre-selected 3 months date prior to today** in bootstrap multidate picker? 
How to set 3 months into the option **setDates option**?
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874375/multiple-dates-in-bootstrap-date-picker) is only to set multi-date select and set only random 2 dates pre-selected, so it is not useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple dates in Bootstrap date-picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874375/multiple-dates-in-bootstrap-date-picker)

Comment: @mariusz how can I set 3 months date pre selected?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to get your date (it's for 30 days ahead so you need to change it for 3 months):

```
var time = new Date();
time.setDate(time.getDate()+30);
alert(time);
```

and play with this to set up your new date:

```
$('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2014, 2, 5));
```

Comment: setdate won't work because it is only for one date to set. I have to use setdates