# Datepicker days not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm having a issue with my datepicker, basically I have a list of days that need to be highlighted and the calendar always shows update, for example days that already have passed the current date are removed from the calendar to keep it updated, the problem is that the rest of the days are not working, the first day is displayed but not the rest. I have everything OK, the code is right, and I even tried to get the variable `serviceDates` data as static and replace by the variable in the update function, and it works, but if i use the variable in the function it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
var serviceDates = [
    "21-12-2019",
    "21-11-2019",
    "22-10-2019",
    "22-09-2019",
    "23-08-2019",
    "24-07-2019",
    "24-06-2019",
    "25-05-2019",
    "25-04-2019",
    "26-03-2019",
    "24-02-2019",
    "25-01-2019"
];

var currentDate = new Date();

for (var i = 0; i < serviceDates.length; i++){
    var formatDate = serviceDates[i].split('-').reverse().join('-');
    if(new Date(formatDate) < currentDate){
        serviceDates.splice(i);
    }
}

var servicesFiltered = serviceDates.join('","');

$('#datepicker').datepicker('update',servicesFiltered);
```

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875629/562424

Comment: thanks @KarthikGanesan this solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think this: `serviceDates.splice(i);` should be this: `serviceDates.splice(i,1);`

> According to MDN: If deleteCount is omitted then all of the elements from start through the end of the array will be deleted.

Comment: has i told in the post the problem isnt the splice, the array is giving all the data correctlly